Package list update of apt-daily.service is failing silently, update-success-stamp despite errors
We have an unattended update setup. To make sure nothing slips, we check for pending security updates and trigger a warning if there is something available but not installed for a week.
Now we have a server with security updates not installed for a while because of the periodic package update failing without any indication of it. We would like to add a trigger to the monitoring to detect this, however, that seems not so simple.
apt update prints an error and has a non-zero exit status:
# apt update
. . . 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
# echo $?
100

However, the above did set the "success" stamp at:
# ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 11 10:58 /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp

Also, despite the error, the systemd service apt-daily.service is exiting with exit status 0.
How is it possible to detect that the daily package update is failing?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"


Try to narrow the problem. Is it the apt source? Or the network? If it's a one-time fix, then there might not be a need to set up ongoing detection or reporting.

What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

@stumblebee: Good point. Done.
